# Manipulation of Geometric Series and Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I was just hoping to confirm that the following manipulations make sense:

Say I begin with $\frac{1}{(1-x)^n}$.  Then we have $(1-x)^{-n} = $$\sum$ $-n\choose k$   $(-x)^k$ = $\sum$ $(-1)^k$ $n+k-1 \choose k$ $(-x)^k$, where our sum runs over k = $0$ to $\infty$.  Does this make sense?

ADDED:

Verifying my example:  $1/(1-3x)^2$ gives $\sum (n+1)3^nx^n$ is that correct?

Comment: The sum runs over $k$ from zero to infinity.

Comment: Right, I'll make that edit.

Comment: You should have $(-x)^k$ in the sum instead of $(x)^k$, otherwise it looks good.

Comment: Got it, in which case we get $(-1)^k$ $(-1)^k$ in front, which is why we needn't worry about them at all in this case, but in the case of $\frac {1}{(1+x)^n}$ we do have to, right?

Comment: Funny, you had $(-x)^k$, then you edited it into $x^k$.

Comment: I thought for a moment that I was manipulating the geometric series instead of the binomial theorem and so I wasn't quite sure if I had mixed up the sign on $x^k$.  I see now though.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have added an extra example if you have a moment to check.

Comment: The example looks OK to me.

Comment: It is correct I think.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to establish the power series expansion is to use that differentation and taking powers just differ by a factor:
$$\delta_{x} (1-x)^{-n} = n! (1-x)^{-(n+1)}$$

For example, $\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{\prime} = \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{2}$ and so on.
So
$$
\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^{n}=\delta_{x}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \delta_{x}^{n-1}(x^{k}) =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(n-1)! m!} x^{m} =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom{m+n-1}{n-1} x^{m}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the coefficient $x^m$ equals the number of ways to divide $n$ into $m$ non-negative partitions (i.e. $x^{p_1}x^{p_2}\cdots x^{p_n}=x^{m}$, with $p_i\geq 0$), which is ${{n+m-1}\choose{n-1}}$.